# Get the best of VS Get the best out of

Tags: expressions, nouns, best-most

I'm wondering if there's a difference in meaning between these two:
Get the best of VS Get the Best out of

1. Get the best of your washing machine 
   I understand that the washing machine might not be that good and that one will give me tips to get the best of it
2. Get the best out of your washing machine
   I understand that whether or not it is a good washing machine, one will give me tips to make it work at full capacity

Is that correct?

Thx in advance,

Comment: My suggestion is to reword the sentence. Following is an example: While reading a washing machine's manual is suggested, it's also wise listening to tips from others who have used it regularly in order to achieve maximum utilization.

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial English usage, **"get the best of"** means to beat whilst in competition, to win to achieve dominance or superiority in some regard - *"we played table tennis, and I **got the best of him** two out of three matches"*, and is sometimes shortened to **"bested"**: *"we raced, running hard, and he **bested** me".*

However **"to get the best out of"** is used to mean you found a method to get the most effort/work/efficacy out of a given person, item or event: *"Her teacher was brilliant: with careful planning, despite her detesting the topic, he **got the best out of her** and she took first marks as a result"* or *"we raced, my son and I, and by running neck and neck, dropping back and surging forward, I **got the best out of him**; he ran as though world's ruin was at his heels".*

So in your case, the only appropriate phrase of the two presented is **"get the best out of"**, but be aware that it connotes that there are special techniques, tricks, or not readily apparent ways to accomplish the tasks at hand.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Get the best of" can also refer to obtaining the best parts of something physical. For instance "My sister got the best of our mother's jewellery after her death" or "He got the best of the meat, I only got the brisket". I agree, though, that this is not the same as "getting the best out of" something. You could "get the best out of" the brisket by stewing it for an extended time.